# Putting string with newline separated words into array

Tags: bash, shell-script, string, array

I currently have a a `bash` variable that holds a string similar to this one,
where each different phrase is separated by a newline:

```
var="1st word
2nd word

4th word"
```

Note there is an empty space in between `"2nd word"` and `"4th word"`.

I would like to place these phrases into an array as such, keeping the empty string in the 2nd index: 
`arr=("1st word"   "2nd word"   ""   "4th word")`

I tried the following code but it seems to ignore the empty space.
`IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a arr <<<"$var"`

Anyone happens to have a solution to this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your approach is that it relies on word-splitting using an *IFS whitespace character* (i.e. newline). As noted in `man bash`:

```
                       Any  character  in IFS that is not IFS whitespace,
   along with any adjacent IFS whitespace characters, delimits a field.  A
   sequence  of  IFS whitespace characters is also treated as a delimiter.
```

So whatever options you pass to `read`, `"$var"` has already been split into 3 tokens, treating the adjacent newlines either side of the empty 3rd line as a single delimiter.

From bash version 4.0, you can instead use `readarray` (or its synonym, `mapfile`) to read whole lines:

```
$ var="1st word
2nd word

4th word"

$ readarray -t arr <<<"$var"

$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="1st word" [1]="2nd word" [2]="" [3]="4th word")
```

If your bash is too old to provide `readarray` / `mapfile`, then you can do it with a loop:

```
$ arr=()
$ while IFS= read -r line; do arr+=("$line"); done <<<"$var"

$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="1st word" [1]="2nd word" [2]="" [3]="4th word")
```

Comment: Is there an alternative way since readarray doesn't work on macOS?

Comment: @lilek3 please see updated answer